# WPF mvvm navigation another way

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm not sure how to make navigation using mvvm. I'm a beginner so I haven't used any framework like mvvm light.

I found good example https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/. But it is not exactly what I'm looking for because in my app each view will cover all window. So when I will change page i will have no controls access from the mainview.

So I decided to make one MainViewModel for changing ViewModels (as in Rachel Blog) but each ViewModel should know about MainViewModel to execute change view. So when I create PageViewModel, I pass in constructor MainViewModel with public method, for example, changeview().

**Is it a good way of doing this? Or, maybe, there's a better way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child viewmodels should not know about main viewmodel.

Instead they should raise events with names like Forward or Back and so forth. ChangeView is the only example you give, so we’ll go with that.

We'll have the child viewmodel expose commands that cause the events to be raised. Buttons or MenuItems in the child view's XAML can bind to the commands to let the user invoke them. You can also do that via Click event handlers calling viewmodel methods in the child view code behind, but commands are more "correct", because at the cost of a little more work in the viewmodel, they make life a lot simpler for creators of views.

Main viewmodel handles those events and changes the active page viewmodel accordingly. So instead of child calling _mainVM.ChangeView(), child raises its own ChangeView event, and the main VM’s handler for that event on the child calls its own method this.ChangeView(). Main VM is the organizer VM, so it owns navigation.

It’s a good rule to make code as agnostic as possible about how and where it’s used. This goes for controls and viewmodels. Imagine if the ListBox class required the parent to be some particular class; that would be frustrating, and unnecessary as well. Events help us write useful child classes that don’t need to know or care anything about which parent uses them. Even if reuse isn’t a possibility, this approach helps you write clean, well-separated classes that are easy to write and maintain.

If you need help with the details, provide more code, and we can go through applying this design to your project.

---

### Example

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        FooViewModel = new FooViewModel();

        FooViewModel.Back += (object sender, EventArgs e) => Back();
    }

    public FooViewModel FooViewModel { get; private set; }

    public void Back()
    {
        //  Change selected page property
    }
}

public class FooViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public event EventHandler Back;

    private ICommand _backCommand;
    public ICommand BackCommand {
        get {
            if (_backCommand == null)
            {
                //  It has to give us a parameter, but we don't have to use it. 
                _backCommand = new DelegateCommand(parameter => OnBack());
            }
            return _backCommand;
        }
    }

    //  C#7 version
    public void OnBack() => Back?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    //  C# <= 5
    //protected void OnBack()
    //{
    //    var handler = Back;
    //    if (handler != null)
    //    {
    //        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    //    }
    //}
}

//  I don't know if you already have a DelegateCommand or RelayCommand class. 
//  Whatever you call it, if you don't have it, here's a quick and dirty one.
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> exec, Func<object, bool> canExec = null)
    {
        _exec = exec;
        _canExec = canExec;
    }

    Action<object> _exec;
    Func<object, bool> _canExec;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExec == null || _canExec(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_exec != null)
        {
            _exec(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

How to invoke `BackCommand` from child XAML:

```
<Button Content="Back" Command="{Binding BackCommand}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for response.
It seems to be ok. But I've no idea how to make it with events. Could you show me simple example how should look ChildViewModel (raise event) and MainViewModel (handle this event). ?

Comment: Should it be in this way? In ChildViewModel I have field type  event Back and in MainViewModel add action to this event?

Comment: I was writing comment morning and didn't have much time so I didn't write any code. I wasn't sure how to use events in this case. I use events with controls and didn't  know it can be use in that way. So thank you very much for that example. I think that everything now is clear.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzydło Cool. If you run into any snags getting it working in your own code, shoot me an @. If you do get it working, you can mark the answer as correct by checking the checkmark on it.